# Как сделать так, чтобы поля не падали друг на друга?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть поле для ввода текста. Есть `label`, который находится в этом поле. Когда нажимаю на поле для ввода текста, `label` поднимается вверх и я ввожу свой текст, но после ввода, допустим, если в поле Email нету символов *@* и *com*, то `label` ложится на введеный текст.

```css
input:focus~label,
input:valid~label {
  top: -5px;
}

.inputbox label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /*color: #fff;*/
  font-size: 1em;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.inputbox input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50PX;
  background: transparent;
  /*border: none;*/
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
  /*color: #fff;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="inputbox">
  <ion-icon name="send-outline"></ion-icon>
  <input type="email" required />
  <label for="">Email</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так, выглядит довольно кастыльно:

В `<input>` добавить `placeholder=""`

```
input:focus ~ label,
input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label,
input:valid:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: С таким правилом браузер реально напрягает проц, и загрузка страницы будет в 3 раза жёстче. User Expirience будет страдать от боли.

Comment: @EugeneX, доказательства будут?)

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.inputbox {
  position: relative;
}

.inputbox input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50PX;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
}

.inputbox label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1em;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.inputbox input:focus~label,
.inputbox input:valid~label,
.inputbox input:not(:placeholder-shown)~label{
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <ion-icon name="send-outline"></ion-icon>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="" required>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
</form>
```